# Mutlisig tansactions with trezor with multiple inputs and outputs not able to broadcast

Tags: testnet, python, multi-signature, trezor

I am trying to do a multisig

here is my final hex

```
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
```

and here is the script I am using

https://pastebin.com/Nvcui563

error I am getting when broadcasting

`Error validating transaction: Error running script for input 1 referencing ac560e33ef8005359fc84544edaab46a42fe65e2bd4b3461bd4cec19bf5a0c8d at 0: Script was NOT verified successfully..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sunny, looks like you just broadcast a valid TXN on those UTXOs, so I assume you figured it out.

For those reading at home, the problem was that there were three addresses in the redeem script:

```
48'/0'/2'0/0
48'/0'/3'0/0
48'/0'/1'0/0
```

But only one address is used (twice) to sign the TXN

```
48'/0'/2'/0/0
```

The result is that your script hash is correct, since you used the proper three addresses, but you don't meet the 2 of 3 requirement to spend since you've only proven ownership of the private keys for `48'/0'/2'/0/0`

I assume you simply corrected the error and added a second address to your script.

Comment: yup that is correct. I got it working.

Comment: what I found interesting looking at the failed TXN is that even though you signed with the same key twice, the signatures were different.  I'll have to go back through the spec and see what info changes on subsequent multisig signing paths.  I would have thought that the serialized TXN would look the same on the first pass as it did on the third.  Apparently not.

Comment: pls post your findings. I would also like to know. thanks

Comment: I'll plagerize your work if you don't mind.  Just leave your pastbin up, as well as this thread.  Easier to reference.  I'll make a new SE question later when I've done my research just to make sure its not already known

Comment: @Sunny, I figured it out, the reason the sigs are different is because they are signing different inputs.  From the wiki on [`OP_SIGCHECK`](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG) (steps 7 and 8) you will see that extra script bits are added to the input your signing.  So when you change from signing `inp1` to `inp1`, even though you use the same key, the extra script bits are in different parts of the signature.